# Table size increased after changing datatype from nchar to varchar

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, alter-table, database-internals

I am facing a strange behavior when changing datatype from **nchar(100)** to **varchar(100)** for one column.

I understand if I change datatype of a column where data is present then it can increase size but in our case initial table is **empty** and datatype is changed **before** table is filled with data. Justification for this on our side is that original table is huge so we copied all the data to a temp table by casting to varchar, truncated the original table, changed datatype and copied the data back. To our surprise, size of the data was still much bigger than expected.
If instead of truncating, we drop and recreate the table then size is very small.

Hope someone can help me understand why SQL server does that. I suppose it is due to how SQL Server maintains internal structure of the table but would be good get some explanation.

Here is a sample code to reproduce this behavior on **SQL Server 2019**.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Base(SomeText varchar(100));
DECLARE @i AS smallint = 1;

WHILE @i <= 10000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Base(SomeText)
    SELECT      @i;

    SET @i+=1;
END

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base_NChar;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Base_NChar(SomeText nchar(100));
ALTER TABLE dbo.Base_NChar ALTER COLUMN SomeText varchar(100);

INSERT INTO dbo.Base_NChar(SomeText)
SELECT      SomeText
FROM        dbo.Base;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base_New;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Base_New(SomeText varchar(100));

INSERT INTO dbo.Base_New(SomeText)
SELECT      SomeText
FROM        dbo.Base;


SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName,
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.name in ('Base', 'Base_NChar', 'Base_New')  
GROUP BY t.name, s.name, p.rows
ORDER BY UsedSpaceKB DESC, t.name;

DROP TABLE dbo.Base;
DROP TABLE dbo.Base_NChar;
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**, a dropped fixed length column remains in table meta-data until the table is rebuilt or recreated, **even if the table was empty when altered**. New rows will contain the dropped fixed length column artifact until the table is rebuilt or recreated. SQL Server does not currently have an optimization to cleanup column meta-data when an empty table is altered.

One can observe the internals of this behavior with the help of undocumented internal system tables and `DBCC PAGE`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Base_NChar(SomeText nchar(100));
ALTER TABLE dbo.Base_NChar ALTER COLUMN SomeText varchar(100);

SELECT
      t.name AS table_name
    , c.name AS column_name
    , ipc.partition_column_id AS column_id
    , ty.name
    , ipc.max_length
    , ipc.is_dropped 
FROM sys.tables AS t
JOIN sys.system_internals_partitions ip ON ip.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.system_internals_partition_columns ipc on ipc.partition_id = ip.partition_id
JOIN sys.types ty ON ty.system_type_id = ipc.system_type_id
LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.object_id = t.object_id AND ipc.partition_column_id = c.column_id
WHERE ip.object_id = object_id('dbo.Base_NChar');
```

| table_name | column_name | column_id | name | max_length | is_dropped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Base_NChar | NULL | 67108865 | nchar | 200 | 1 |
| Base_NChar | SomeText | 1 | varchar | 100 | 0 |

As you can see, the `nchar` column still exists in meta-data. Furthermore, the dropped column is still present in newly inserted rows. Here are snippets of a dump of the first row (slot 0) of the first page for each table in your question:

Table `dbo.Base` shows the 1 byte Column 1 value of the `varchar(100)` column:

```
Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 12

Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP VARIABLE_COLUMNS
Record Size = 12                    
Memory Dump @0x000000B45A3F0060

0000000000000000:   30000400 01000001 000c0031                    0..........1

Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0xb Length 1 Length (physical) 1

SomeText = 1
```

Table `dbo.Base_NNChar` shows the 200 byte dropped `nchar` column (Column 67108865) and the 1 byte `varchar(100)` Column 1:

```
Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 212

Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP VARIABLE_COLUMNS
Record Size = 212                   
Memory Dump @0x000000B45A3F0060

0000000000000000:   3000cc00 00000000 c4d86da1 fa7f0000 ffffffff  0.Ì.....ÄØm¡ú...ÿÿÿÿ
0000000000000014:   ffffffff ff658e9d fa7f0000 6ae760cc 4c020000  ÿÿÿÿÿeŽ.ú...jç`ÌL...
0000000000000028:   00000000 00000000 01000000 b4000000 ffffffff  ............´...ÿÿÿÿ
000000000000003C:   ffffffff feffffff ffffffff 68e0a26f 4b020000  ÿÿÿÿþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿhà¢oK...
0000000000000050:   d099f3cb 4c020000 f1907aa1 fa7f0000 1099f3cb  Ð.óËL...ñ.z¡ú.....óË
0000000000000064:   4c020000 00000000 00000000 306f3f5a b4000000  L...........0o?Z´...
0000000000000078:   c4d86da1 fa7f0000 d099f3cb 4c020000 14887aa1  ÄØm¡ú...Ð.óËL.....z¡
000000000000008C:   fa7f0000 10e760cc 4c020000 d099f3cb 4c020000  ú....ç`ÌL...Ð.óËL...
00000000000000A0:   c0e760cc 4c020000 9086f3cb 4c020000 0089f3cb  Àç`ÌL....†óËL....‰óË
00000000000000B4:   4c020000 00000000 00000000 10000000 00000000  L...................
00000000000000C8:   5087f3cb 02000001 00d40031                    P‡óË.....Ô.1

Slot 0 Column 67108865 Offset 0x4 Length 0 Length (physical) 200

DROPPED = NULL                      

Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0xd3 Length 1 Length (physical) 1

SomeText = 1
```

Table `dbo.Base_New` shows the 1 byte Column 1 value of the `varchar(100)` column, just like `dbo.Base`:

```
Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 12

Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP VARIABLE_COLUMNS
Record Size = 12                    
Memory Dump @0x000000B4607F0060

0000000000000000:   30000400 01000001 000c0031                    0..........1

Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0xb Length 1 Length (physical) 1

SomeText = 1
```

> Justification for this on our side is that original table is huge so
> we copied all the data to a temp table by casting to varchar,
> truncated the original table, changed datatype and copied the data
> back.

Be aware of another gotcha with the above technique. Simply casting the `nchar(100)` value to `varchar(100)` will retain the trailing spaces from the `nchar` value. You'll also need to trim the trailing spaces to avoid the padding the `varchar` value: `RTRIM(CAST(SomeText AS varchar(100)))`

Below is the script I used to get this information, including a modified version of a `DBCC PAGE` utility proc I use in some of my SQL presentations.

```
--utility proc to dump pages
CREATE OR ALTER PROC #usp_DumpPages
      @ObjectName nvarchar(247) --name of table or indexed view
    , @IndexName sysname --name of index or NULL for heap
    , @PartitionNumber int = NULL --partition number or NULL for all partitions
    , @dbcc_page_print_option int = NULL --
    , @page_count_limit int = 1
AS
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE 
      @database_id int = DB_ID()
    , @object_id int = OBJECT_ID(@ObjectName)
    , @index_id int = CASE WHEN @IndexName IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE INDEXPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@ObjectName), @IndexName, 'IndexId') END --dump heap data pages when index name is null
    , @allocated_page_file_id int
    , @allocated_page_page_id int
    , @page_level int
    , @page_sequence int
    , @page_count int = 0;

BEGIN TRY

    IF @object_id IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Specified object (%s) not found', 16, 0, @ObjectName);
    END;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = @object_id AND index_id = @index_id)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Specified index (%s) not found', 16, 0, @IndexName);
    END;
    
    --get data/index pages in logical order
    DECLARE pages CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    WITH
        pages AS (
            SELECT
                  allocated_page_file_id
                , allocated_page_page_id
                , previous_page_file_id
                , previous_page_page_id
                , next_page_file_id
                , next_page_page_id
                , page_level
                , 0 AS page_sequence
            FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(@database_id, @object_id, @index_id, @PartitionNumber, 'DETAILED')
            WHERE 
                page_type_desc IN ( 'DATA_PAGE', 'INDEX_PAGE' )
        )
        , chained_pages AS (
            SELECT
                  allocated_page_file_id
                , allocated_page_page_id
                , next_page_file_id
                , next_page_page_id
                , page_level
                , 1 AS page_sequence
            FROM pages
            WHERE 
                previous_page_page_id IS NULL --first page of each level
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                  next_page.allocated_page_file_id
                , next_page.allocated_page_page_id
                , next_page.next_page_file_id
                , next_page.next_page_page_id
                , next_page.page_level
                , chained_pages.page_sequence + 1 AS page_sequence
            FROM pages AS next_page
            JOIN chained_pages ON
                next_page.allocated_page_file_id = chained_pages.next_page_file_id
                AND next_page.allocated_page_page_id = chained_pages.next_page_page_id
        )
    SELECT
          allocated_page_file_id
        , allocated_page_page_id
        , page_level
        , page_sequence
    FROM chained_pages
    ORDER BY page_sequence
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000);
    
    --return DBCC results to client
    DBCC TRACEON(3604) WITH NO_INFOMSGS; 
    
    --dump pages in logical order
    OPEN pages;
    WHILE @page_count < @page_count_limit
    BEGIN
    
        FETCH NEXT FROM pages INTO @allocated_page_file_id, @allocated_page_page_id, @page_level, @page_sequence;
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;

        SET @page_count += 1;
    
        --dump page
        IF @dbcc_page_print_option IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DBCC PAGE( @database_id, @allocated_page_file_id, @allocated_page_page_id, @dbcc_page_print_option ) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
        END
    
    END
    CLOSE pages;
    DEALLOCATE pages;
    
    --don't return DBCC results to client any more
    DBCC TRACEOFF(3604) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DBCC TRACEOFF(3604) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Base(SomeText varchar(100));
DECLARE @i AS smallint = 1;

WHILE @i <= 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Base(SomeText)
    SELECT      @i;

    SET @i+=1;
END

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base_NChar;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Base_NChar(SomeText nchar(100));
ALTER TABLE dbo.Base_NChar ALTER COLUMN SomeText varchar(100);

INSERT INTO dbo.Base_NChar(SomeText)
SELECT      SomeText
FROM        dbo.Base;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base_New;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Base_New(SomeText varchar(100));

INSERT INTO dbo.Base_New(SomeText)
SELECT      SomeText
FROM        dbo.Base;

PRINT '****** dbo.Base';
EXEC #usp_DumpPages @ObjectName = N'dbo.Base', @IndexName = NULL, @dbcc_page_print_option = 3;
PRINT '****** dbo.Base_NChar';
EXEC #usp_DumpPages @ObjectName = N'dbo.Base_NChar', @IndexName = NULL, @dbcc_page_print_option = 3;
PRINT '****** dbo.Base_New';
EXEC #usp_DumpPages @ObjectName = N'dbo.Base_New', @IndexName = NULL, @dbcc_page_print_option = 3;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base_NChar;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Base_New;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS #usp_DumpPages;
GO
```

Comment: thanks Dan for a very good explanation. Hope this also helps others to realize that altering datatype is not always the best option even if you plan migrate data later.

Answer (score 0):

> original table is huge so we copied all the data to a temp table by casting to varchar, truncated the original table, changed datatype and copied the data back

Dan [has explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/332152) why the table size increased.

I just want to add that a simpler way to achieve space savings is to enable row (or page) compression on the original table directly. This saves copying the data out and back.

Lightweight [row compression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/row-compression-implementation) alone will save all the trailing space in the `nchar` column and also store Unicode characters in one byte in most cases via [Unicode compression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/unicode-compression-implementation).

Taken together, these two aspects will save as much space as the conversion to `varchar` and possibly more since other columns may also benefit from row compression.

You also do not risk data corruption when changing Unicode to `varchar` (unless a UTF-8 collation is used).